# Element exists on the page in Playwright.js but $ returns null

Tags: javascript, playwright

in my sample js code

```
let targetXpath = 'xpath=//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/h2/a/span'
let name1 = await page.locator(targetXpath).evaluate(node => node.innerText)
console.log(name1) // prints the name of the item being looked at on the xpath

edit: I should have noted I tried both statements separately. So if you comment out name1 and console.log(name1), And I was trying to do this on amazon searching for nvidia 3060

let nameDollar1 = await page.$(targetXpath)
console.log(nameDollar1) // prints null
```

How is playwright able to see this when calling evaluate but not able to see it when using $()?

Comment: You code worked for me, using console.log(nameDollar1)

Comment: I should have noted I tried both statements separately. So if you comment out name1 and console.log(name1), And I was trying to do this on amazon searching for nvidia 3060

Comment: @pyericl : can you post the html you want to get the value or share the url?

Comment: @Kunduk. There wasn't actually any html. Playwright had me writing my code in a IIFE which I had to run from the terminal. When I do try to implement it in the front end I get errors. Sorry for the late response

Answer (score 1):

Locators are waiting for elements to appear and have strict mode (makes sure that there is only 1 element on the page with the given selector) enabled. Page.$ and Page.$$ on the other hand (some Playwright language bindings also call it querySelector and querySelectorAll) don't wait for the elements and also don't have strict mode enabled. Thats why its null in your case.

Keep also in mind that locators resolve the element when the action (click, fill, etc.) gets executed and $/$$ resolve the element when they are getting called. See here for more information: https://playwright.dev/docs/locators

General rule: Always use Locators.

Comment: Oh I get it now. That explains why it works when both lines are uncommented. Locator makes sure it shows up first before $(nameDollar1) so it printing nameDollar1 works then
Thanks